# How can I create and update static blocks via a module install script?

Tags: import, magento-2.1, static-content

I have a number of static blocks and pages I need to create in a few shops and without doing it manually I copied the install script for the sample data for Magento2 to use a .csv to install these blocks.

Similar to this question [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117750/how-can-i-create-static-blocks-via-a-module-install-script), I am looking for a way I can later update these static blocks also over a .csv.

Based on this I have added the following files to upgrade the static blocks but it is not working.
http://www.learnmagento.com/magento-2-create-cms-static-blocks-via-setup-script/

I have added an `UpgradeData.php` with the following content

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\Page;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
      /**
     * @var \Magento\CmsSampleData\Model\Page
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CmsSampleData\Model\Block
     */
    private $block;

    /**
     * @param \my\module\Model\Page $page
     * @param \my\module\Model\Block $block
     */
    public function __construct(
        \my\module\Model\Page $page,
        \my\module\Model\Block $block
    ) {
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->block = $block;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //handle all possible upgrade versions

        if(!$context->getVersion()) {
            //no previous version found, installation, InstallSchema was just executed
            //be careful, since everything below is true for installation !
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3') < 0) {
            //$this->page->install(['my_module::fixtures/pages/pages.csv']);
            $this->block->upgrade(
                [
                    'my_module::fixtures/blocks/pages_static_blocks.csv',
                ]
            );

        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

And in `/Model/Block.php` I have added this function

```
public function upgrade(array $fixtures)
{
    foreach ($fixtures as $fileName) {
        $fileName = $this->fixtureManager->getFixture($fileName);
        if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
            continue;
        }

        $rows = $this->csvReader->getData($fileName);
        $header = array_shift($rows);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $data = [];
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $data[$header[$key]] = $value;
            }
            $row = $data;
            $data = $this->converter->convertRow($row);
            $cmsBlock = $this->saveCmsBlock($data['block']);
            $cmsBlock->unsetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea whats wrong or am I missing something essential?